# Extract http link from html element

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

Symantec recently changed their download page which moved to broadcom. Since then `Invoke-WebRequest` cannot grab the http url for the `v5i64.exe` file.

However the http url can be found when using Developer Tools in the browser looking at the Elements level, inside the body section of the page.

Does anyone have an idea on how this daily-changed url can be extracted with PowerShell?

```
$webreq = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.broadcom.com/support/security-center/definitions/download/detail?gid=sep"
$webreq.Links | Select href
```

Comment: The reason is that the link is not part of the page you are downloading. Symantec is constructing the page from downloads that it is later processing after the initial page loads.

Comment: Thanks John for the prompt feedback. In this case, is it possible to download/dump the page in temp variable, simulating the human loading of the page? And then to extract the link?

Answer (score 0):

Use IE via ComObject

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible=$True
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
$IE.navigate2("https://www.broadcom.com/support/security-center/definitions/download/detail?gid=sep")
while ($IE.busy) {
     start-sleep -milliseconds 1000 #wait 1 second interval to load page 
      }
```

Then find elementy by `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("element name")`

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell script will prompt you to download the links containing the text `v5i64.exe` and `HTTPS`. This works on PowerShell 5.1 for Windows. It does not work for PowerShell 6 or 7 (PowerShell Core).

Tested on Windows 10.0.18363.657, Internet Explorer 11.657.18362, PowerShell 5.1.18362.628

```
$url = "https://www.broadcom.com/support/security-center/definitions/download/detail?gid=sep"

$outfile = "./v5i64.exe"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

$ie.visible=$True

while($ie.Busy) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

$ie.navigate2($url)

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {
    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 500
} 

$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | % {
    if ($_.ie8_href -like "*v5i64.exe") {
        if ($_.ie8_href -like "https://*") {
            $len = (Invoke-WebRequest $_.ie8_href -Method Head).Headers.'Content-Length'
            Write-Host "File:" $_.ie8_href
            Write-Host "Size:" $len
            $confirm = Read-Host "Download file? [y/n]"
            if ($confirm -eq "y") {
                Write-Host "Downloading" $_.ie8_href

                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.ie8_href -OutFile $outfile
            }
        }
    }
}

$ie.Stop()
$ie.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the proposed solutions. However here is my final code I am using:

```
$SEP_last_link = ("http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/"+($SEP_last | Select-String release -NotMatch | select -Last 1))
    $Symantec_folder = "C:\Download for DVD\Symantec"
    $Symantec_filepath = "$Symantec_folder\$SEP_last"

    if (!(Test-Path "$Symantec_filepath" -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host "`rStart to download Symantec $SEP_last file: $(Get-Date)`r"
    $start_time = (Get-Date)
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.DownloadFile($SEP_last_link, $Symantec_filepath)
    Write-Host "`r$SEP_last file has been downloaded successfully`r" -ForegroundColor Green
    $end_time = $(get-date) - $start_time
    $total_time = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$end_time.Ticks)
    Write-Host "`rTime to download Symantec $SEP_last file: $total_time`r"
} else {
  Write-Host "`rSymantec $SEP_last file already exists!`r" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

    Get-ChildItem -Path "$Symantec_Folder\*-v5i64.exe" -Exclude "$SEP_last" -Verbose –Force | Remove-Item
```